# The preopen set

Tags: general-topology

‎‎A subset ‎‎$‎S‎$‎ of ‎$‎(X, ‎\tau)‎$‎ is said to ‎be‎ ‎"preopen" if ‎$‎S ‎\subset‎ \text{int}(\text{cl}(S)‎)‎$‎‎.‎‎‎
‎The family of ‎all ‎preopen ‎subsets of $‎(X, ‎\tau)‎$‎ is denoted by $\text{PO}‎(X, ‎\tau)‎$‎.‎
‎The complement of a ‎preopen ‎‎set in ‎$‎(X, ‎\tau) $‎ is called ‎preclosed.‎
The intersection of all members of the family of ‎all ‎preclosed‎ sets in ‎$(X, ‎\tau)‎$‎ containing a set ‎‎$‎S‎$‎ is called ‎the ‎"preclosure"‎ of ‎‎$‎S‎$‎ and is denoted ‎by ‎‎$‎\text{pcl}‎_{‎\tau‎}‎(‎S)‎‎$‎.‎

I can prove that, if $S$ is preclosed, $‎\text{pcl}‎_{‎\tau‎}‎(‎S)‎‎ = S$, but I cannot prove when $‎\text{pcl}‎_{‎\tau‎}‎(‎S) = \text{cl}‎_{‎\tau‎}‎(S)$. **Except that $S$ is closed, is there any other condition that $\text{‎pcl}‎_{‎\tau‎}‎(‎S) = \text{cl}‎_{‎\tau‎}‎(S)$?** I mean, if $S$ is preopen, preclosed, or both of them, or $X$ is extremally disconnected, or any other condition, is $\text{‎pcl}‎_{‎\tau‎}‎(‎S) = \text{cl}‎_{‎\tau‎}‎(S)$?

Can you help me?

- ($S$ is preclosed is $\text{cl}(\text{int}(S)) \subset S$.)
- An extremally disconnected space is a topological space in which the closure of every open set is open.

Answer (score 1):

Some ideas: note that not only a preclosed set is equal to its preclosure, but also the other way: a set equal to its preclosure is preclosed. In other words, any intersection of preclosed sets is still preclosed.

You may want to look at the classical Kuratowski closure complement problem to get some intuition on how a set can look like with respect to its Kuratowski operations.

You have proposed some conditions – if you can't find a proof, try to find a counterexample.

Comment: what do you mean about "the classical Kuratowski closure complement problem"?

Comment: Is there relationship between preopen set and the classical Kuratowski closure complement problem?

Comment: The classical formulation is "how many different sets can one obtain from a fixed set $A$ by applying the operators of closure and complement iteratively"… we can call these operators Kuratowski operators – closure, interior, complement, and all compositions. Preopenness is defined by means of Kuratowski operators: a set is preopen if it is contained in the interior of its closure.